# Horizontally concatenating dataframes gives unexpected numbers of rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two data frames. One is df_1 - `217*9` size and another one is df_2 - `217*5`. I want to concatenate them horizontally. Note that there is no key column. I tried to concatenate them using the following code

```
df = pd.concat([df_1, df_2], axis=1, ignore_index=True)
```

But I am getting the resulting one with `256*22` size and with unexpected results. I just need to concatenate them horizontally. What would be the issue here?

Comment: Maybe remove the ignore_index=True. Meaning that your code will look like: df = pd.concat([df_1, df_2], axis=1). I believe this default code simply just pastes the df_2 on the right side of your df_1

Comment: Could you maybe show some snippets of df_1 and df_2? I tried it in some small example and actually it was behaving as expected. Maybe there is something odd with your data? ignore_index=True is just a bit strange then, as it leaves the returned DataFrame with no column names, but maybe this is what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is the index of your two data frames that are not distinct.
By giving `ignore_index=True` while having `axis=1` it will only ignore the column-indices, not the row indices.

You could try resetting the indices while concatting like here:

`pd.concat([df_1.reset_index().drop("index", axis=1), df_2.reset_index().drop("index", axis=1)], axis=1)`

Edit: I've seen, that you accepted the answer before my last edit. My first solution still had a problem though: Leaving the ignore_index=True led to additional columns and when setting it to False, there were the index-columns multiple times included. I changed the code a bit to drop those new index columns. That might not be the best solution but I think it works.